# DatePicker - Next.js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side, supabase

I am new to using next.js and I have encountered a problem. My goal is to retrieve information from a date picker and use it to fetch data from Supabase. The data fetched will depend on the user's selection.

However, I am currently facing an issue where I am unable to select the user's dates and search for the user on the server side render page.

Supabase code:

```
//get all tickets from supabase
const { data } = await supabase.from('tickets').select('*')
```

Datepicker:

```
 <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
     <DatePickerWithRange />
 </div>
```

date-range-picker.tsx:

```
"use client"
export function DatePickerWithRange({
  className,
}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState<DateRange | undefined>({
    from: new Date(),
    to: subDays(new Date(), 20),
  })

  return (
    <div className={cn("grid gap-2", className)}>
      <Popover>
        <PopoverTrigger asChild>
          <Button
            id="date"
            variant={"outline"}
            className={cn(
              "w-[300px] justify-start text-left font-normal",
              !date && "text-muted-foreground"
            )}
          >
            <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
            {date?.from ? (
              date.to ? (
                <>
                  {format(date.from, "LLL dd, y")} -{" "}
                  {format(date.to, "LLL dd, y")}
                </>
              ) : (
                format(date.from, "LLL dd, y")
              )
            ) : (
              <span>Pick a date</span>
            )}
          </Button>
        </PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
          <Calendar
            initialFocus
            mode="range"
            defaultMonth={date?.from}
            selected={date}
            onSelect={setDate}
            numberOfMonths={1}
          />
        </PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Anything you can help me with will be welcome